# Website hosted on Godaddy, But want to use Amazon CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website hosted on GoDaddy. I want to use Amazon CloudFront for serving it to visitors.

I have searched and only found hosting the media on S3 or the entire site on EC2. I do not want that

Is it possible that once a while, say 15 minutes, Amazon CF gets the latest data of my website from godaddy server and any visitor is served the content from Amazon CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html#concept_CustomOrigin), CloudFront supports using any source that can respond to http requests as a `Custom Origin`.

Create a custom origin and associate a behaviour with that origin and you’ll be serving your content, from your custom HTTP origin, via CloudFront.